# Facing error in opening cloudera quickstart vm 5.4.2-0- virtual box

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have recently installed oracle virtual box and  i have imported  cloudera quickstart  vm 5.4.2-0 i have encountered  this error

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

how could i fix this    help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether virtualization is enabled in your machine? You can cite to [how to enable in bios](http://amiduos.com/support/knowledge-base/article/enabling-virtualization-in-bios)

Comment: thanks i have solved it by enabling  virtualization . my new bios set up was not trivial so it gets some time to find it :P thank you for your reply  @akki